# vuejs, the v-model derective can bind the json

Tags: vue.js

```
 var data=new Vue({
        el:"body",
        data:{
        user:{
        name:"tom",
        nickname:"tom1"
        }
        }
        });
```

Can i use the way in html?

```
<input type="text" v-model="user.name"/>
 <input type="text" v-model="user.nickname"/>
```

I meet a trouble in this way ,the console

```
vue.min.js:6    TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

**Html**

```
<div id="editor">
      <input type="text" v-model="user.name"/>
     <input type="text" v-model="user.nickname"/>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    user:{
        name:"tom",
        nickname:"tom1"
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: i use the same of this way in https://jsfiddle.net/5y5dvucv/ .。it's work on jsfinddle ,but not in my program

Comment: check the vue js version you imported in your program

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, see the snippet with the prop user.name changed by code and updating the Input text through Two-way data-binding functionality.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      user:{
          name:"tom",
          nickname:"tom1"
          }
    },
    methods: {
     onClick() {
       this.user.name = 'Tomas'
       console.log(this.user.name)
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="editor">
      <input type="text" v-model="user.name"/>
     <input type="text" v-model="user.nickname"/>
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="onClick">Change name by code</button>
</div>
```